# Differences between Proxima Nova Cond and Proxima Nova A Cond?

Tags: fonts, typography

Trying to get this font for a client and got stuck trying to figure out the difference(s) between Proxima Nova Cond and Proxima Nova **A** Cond?

I notice the lowercase 'a' is different (together with all 'a' derivate glyphs), something which is presumably also suggested in the name of the 'A' version, but anyone worked with these and can explain if there's any other differences?

- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/cond-light/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/proxima-nova/acond-light/

Answer (score 1):

If you check the full glyph table you'll see that many of the accented characters are different, plus the lowercase glyphs (y, l) and their accented versions. So probably an alternate font for those that want slightly different glyphs.

Comment: Yeap thanks. I did see the glyph chart and yes apparently many differences, but apparently indeed the most important seems to be in how the lowercase 'a' is built.